# PHP Sanitizing a cookie with filter_input_array INPUT_COOKIE

Tags: php, cookies

I've got a remember me cookie set like this with PHP:

```
setcookie('Rememb', 'id='.$id.'&auth='.$hash, time()+60*60*24*30, '/', '.domain.com', false, true);
```

I then check the cookie in my script with:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['Rememb'])) {
}
```

Is it possible to sanitize `$id` and $auth with `filter_input_array` `INPUT_COOKIE` ?

I can't find anything in the PHP doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$san = md5($id . $auth); 
setcookie ('Rememb', $san, time()+60*60*24*30, '/', '.domain.com');

if (isset($_COOKIE['Rememb'])) {  
   $checkSan = $_COOKIE['Rememb'];
   if ($checkSan == md5($id . $auth) return true; else return false;
}
```

Comment: I'll try to update my login script to use this structure. Thanks for your help Youri.

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept my answer as a 'answer'.